# Windows Phone app background image

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to change the background image for all my xaml pages in the app.xaml, unsuccessfully.

I'm trying the following, in the App constructor:

```
var imageBrush = new ImageBrush
{
    ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/SomeBackgroundImage.png", UriKind.Relative))
};

RootFrame.Background = imageBrush;
```

I don't want to do this at the page level, as all pages will have the same background image depending on the theme selected by the user.

Ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You could easily add a property to a BaseViewModel and bind to it on each page (you could probably use Find & Replace to make the change, even)

Comment: I don't want to do it at the page level. Why adding to every single page when it could be done in the app level? I'll keep your idea in my back pocket, in case I don't sort this out. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I ended up doing:

I created a method that chooses the correct background image, depending on the theme selected.

```
public static ImageBrush GetBackground()
{
    var imageBrush = new ImageBrush();

    if ((Visibility)App.Current.Resources["PhoneLightThemeVisibility"] == Visibility.Visible)
    { 
        imageBrush = new ImageBrush
        {
            ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/Background1.png", UriKind.Relative))
        };
    }
    else
    {
        imageBrush = new ImageBrush
        {
            ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/Background2.png", UriKind.Relative))
        };
    }

    return imageBrush;
}
```

And in each page I set the background image.

```
LayoutRoot.Background = Utils.GetBackground();
```

Comment: the buildaction should be content for the image

Answer (score 2):

Though your code snippet didn't work for me either, using

```
RootFrame.Background = App.Current.Resources["MainBackground"] as ImageBrush;
```

does. You'll need to add the following to your resources dictionary in `App.xaml`

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="MainBackground" ImageSource="/resources/MainBackground.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a custom style to make my frame background white:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="WhiteTemplate" TargetType="toolkit:TransitionFrame">
                <Grid x:Name="ClientArea">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/yourimage.png"
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="FirstContentPresenter"  />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="SecondContentPresenter" />

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

Then, in App.xaml.cs

```
private void CompleteInitializePhoneApplication(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // Set the root visual to allow the application to render
            if (RootVisual != RootFrame)
                RootVisual = RootFrame;

            // Remove this handler since it is no longer needed
            RootFrame.Navigated -= CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;
            // Add this to inject the media element Control template
            RootFrame.Template = Current.Resources["WhiteTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
        }
```

Note that this is using the Toolkit.. If you aren't using it, you should probably use 'PhoneApplicationFrame' instead of toolkit:TransitionFrame

Comment: Your idea is interesting, but having to create a template just to change the background image of all pages seems like an overkill to me. Why doesn't my original code work? That's my main question...