# Save App.RootFrame Background in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am using `PhotoChooserTask`to pick a picture from photo gallery and then set this picture as my app background. Everything works fine, but when I exit my application it's not saved. What I am looking is to save this background for my application.
I am using below code:

```
photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask()
photoChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photoChooserTask_Completed);

void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
       System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings settings = System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

       System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
       bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
       imgCustom.Source = bmp;

       System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush backgroundBrush = new System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush() { ImageSource = bmp };
       App.RootFrame.Background = backgroundBrush;

   }
}
```

What I am looking is, If I close and run my application, This background should not change unless the user changes it.

Thanks!

Comment: The solution is in below link:

[How to set and save background image in windows phone][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013737/how-to-set-and-save-background-image-in-windows-phone

Answer (score 0):

How about trying out this piece of code at the end:

```
var frame = App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
frame.Background = backgroundBrush;
```

Reference: [Windows Phone app background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045848/)

Comment: Thanks, my point is not to set the background. My code works and the background is changing. However its not saved. If I close my app and reopen it the background is gone. What I want is that the background should be saved.

Comment: I guess there's something wrong with the `BitmapImage`, because as I searched for some, I came across saying to use the above instead of `App.RootFrame.Background`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483812/error-in-changing-the-background-dynamically

Comment: Thanks, I still insist that the background is changing. The point is how can I save this background next time I open my app?